# Convert timestamp to date?

Tags: php

I have an array which gives:

```
array ( 
   0 => 'Fri Mar 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)-Mon Mar 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)', 
   1 => 'Tue Mar 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)-Sat Mar 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)' 
)
```

I try to have it like this format `'m/d/Y'` -> eg. `13/03/2020`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
foreach($dates as $item) {
  echo "<li>".date('d/m/Y',$item)."</li>";
}
```

But says:

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in

I'm looking for

```
13/03/2020-16/03/2020 & 17/03/2020-21/03/2020
```

Comment: `$item` needs to be a number. What is its value?

Comment: The string with the date and time components must be parsed first. Either with class DateTime or with strtotime()

Comment: Can you var_export the array. Not sure I really understand what the array is.

Comment: So which of those two dates do you want to transform, and what should the output look like

Comment: @Andreas I need all dates present in the array and which have timestamp

Comment: updating the question with the var export

Comment: @Andreas I'm looking for this output `13/03/2020-16/03/2020 & 17/03/2020-21/03/2020`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `foreach()`, couple of `explode()` and `strtotime()`

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    $exploded = explode('-',$arr);
    $finalTime = '';
    foreach($exploded as $explode){
        $timeString = trim(explode('(',$explode)[0]);
        $finalTime .= (!empty($finalTime)) ? "-".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($timeString)) : date('d/m/Y', strtotime($timeString));
    }
    echo $finalTime;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/77uLI  OR https://3v4l.org/91QIh

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array and use regex to find the dates and str_replace to replace them with the new parsed date.

```
foreach($arr as &$val){
    preg_match_all("/(\w{3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/", $val, $matches);
    foreach($matches[1] as $m){
        $val = str_replace($m, date("m/d/Y", strtotime($m)), $val);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/hgPSg